# Adding values of two column which datatypes are in string format in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The log files is in json format,i extracted the data to dataframe of pyspark
There are two column whose values are in int but datatype of column is string.

```
cola|colb
45|10
10|20
```

Expected Output

```
newcol
55
30
```

but I am getting output like

```
4510    
1020
```

Code i have used like

```
df = .select (F.concat("cola","colb") as newcol).show()
```

kindly help me how can i get correct output.

Comment: Cast the columns to `int` and then add them using `sum` or `+`. `concat` (short for concatenate) is used to add strings.

Comment: why are you using concat for sum?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col

>>> df.show()
+----+----+
|cola|colb|
+----+----+
|  45|  10|
|  10|  20|
+----+----+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- cola: string (nullable = true)
 |-- colb: string (nullable = true)

>>> df.withColumn("newcol", col("cola") + col("colb")).show()
+----+----+------+
|cola|colb|newcol|
+----+----+------+
|  45|  10|  55.0|
|  10|  20|  30.0|
+----+----+------+
```